# tmux multi-key key binding like in screen possible?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, gnu-screen

`screen` offers this functionality:

> ```
> bindkey -t foo stuff barfoo
>    Make  "foo"  an  abbreviation of the word "barfoo".
>    Timeout is disabled so that users can type slowly.
> ```

I use(d) this for e.g.

```
bindkey -t .,u stuff user.name
bindkey -t .,U stuff User.Name
bindkey -t .,E stuff User.Name@My.Domain.tld
```

and so forth.

But now I moved to tmux, for various reasons, and am having difficulties replicating this behavior/functionality on tmux.

When trying to bind e.g. '.,E' I get an "unknown key" error from tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) doesn't have this functionality. It uses a single key in each key-table, with modifiers. Some keys have names [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140007/what-are-valid-keys-for-tmux) for a list.

If you are using a program such as [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) that uses [the gnu readline library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)
then you can use it to do the conversion.

Using bash

```
bind '".,u":"user.Name"'
bind '".,U":"User.Name"'
bind '".,E":"User.Name@My.Domain.tld"'
```

See [readline manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html) for more information.

Comment: Very useful work-around (+1). Thank you for posting.