# In tmux, is there a way to list unbound keys?

Tags: tmux

I know it's easy to list all keybindings in tmux, for example with <kbd>*prefix*</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> or `tmux list-keys`, but I want to get a list of *all keys that are **not yet bound** to anything*, to more easily see what is available for things I'm adding.

Does tmux provide any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked out all the details, but it would be possible to take

1. [a list of all keys supported by tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140007/3358)
2. a list of all keys currently bound, with something like `tmux list-keys -a -N -T prefix | awk '{ print $1 }'`, and
3. use `comm` to remove bound keys and leave all unbound keys.

It would be better if tmux itself could give us this list, since that would be more reliable, however.